# in_array returning false when it should return true

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code :

```
$stopwords = file("/path/to/my-file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo($stopwords[0]." - ");

$words = explode(" ", "alors on danse");
echo($words[0]." - ");

if (in_array($words[0], $stopwords)) {
    echo("yay");
} else {
    echo("nay");
}
```

And I always get `alors - alors - nay` as a result, when I'm expecting `alors - alors - yay`

I've seen a few topics on here regarding similar problems and the solutions were almost always to use the trim() function on the elements of the list array. Which I tried, but it didn't change anything.

Could you please help me realize what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: what is `stopwords` ?

Comment: Can you show `$stopwords` and is `alors` actually in it?

Comment: Where's `$stopwords` ?

Comment: ok..a fifths time: where is `$stopwords`

Comment: I used $list as a more "generic" sounding name for a variable in my exemple, but ended up copying the name I used in my code on the second instance. I can guarantee you that I use $stopwords both times in my code just as in the example after the edit, so the problem doesn't stem from there. Sorry about that

Comment: So right before the `if` statement, try printing $stopwords, and see if `alors` is in it.

Comment: I just run your code in localhost, and it returns `alors - alors - yay` as expected *(assuming the second line was meant to be `echo($stopwords[0]." - ");`)*, so I can't reproduce your issue. Also, it took me 10 minutes to understand what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @jh314 I did a printr on $stopwords just before the if statement and I can guarantee alors is still in it. I tried using in_array() with other words in my-file.txt and it works. I tried putting 'alors' on the second line and it worked. It seems that it only doesn't work with the words on the first line of the text file.

Comment: @Petr R. : sorry, I didn't want to get to specific and tried to create a 'dummy' general example. Seems I shouldn't have as it only made things worse on all accounts

Comment: @PrimsFr: "It seems that it only doesn't work with the words on the first line of the text file" this gave me an idea: is your my-file.txt in utf8? then maybe it is saved as utf8 with BOM - a byte order mask, that consist of bytes that are not shown as text, but nevertheless are part of the first word, as there will be no ' ' between them and the first real word. If that's the case, try saving the file as utf8 without BOM (for example with notepad++)

Comment: @cypherabe : Thanks a lot, it fixed the problem. If you want too, put this as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that it only doesn't work with the words on the first line of
>   the text file

this gave me an idea: is your my-file.txt in utf8?

it may be saved as **utf8 with BOM** - a byte order mark, that consist of bytes that are not shown as text when viewed as utf8, but will be interpreted as part of the first word, if there is no whitespace character between them and the first real word. ([wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ) (for this reason, BOM is not recommended for use with utf8, but some editors have it still as default).

If that's the case, **try saving the file as utf8 without BOM** (for example using notepad++)

Conclusion:
Encoding is a b*tch, sometimes it's necessary to not only look at the displayed text, but to use a hex editor or similar tools to check if the strings not only look alike but are really the same byte sequence

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if `$words` is in `$list`:

```
if(in_array($words[0], $list)) {
...
}
```

or define `$stopwords`:

```
$stopwords = $list;
```

Comment: It was a mistake when copying my code on here. I use the right array as the haystack in my code, so the problem doesn't stem from here. Sorry for this inconvenience ;)